# Obtener la suma de los dos primeros dígitos de un entero en java

Tags: java

Me plantearon este ejercicio: 
Leer un numero entero y obtener la suma de los dos primeros dígitos, verifique que el número es entero positivo y mayor a 9, emplear una función. 
No logro separar los dos primeros digitos y sumarlos.
¡Gracias!

Comment: favor de leer [ask], checa también el [tour]; en que parte estas teniendo problemas? que no sabes hacer?

Comment: El problema lo tengo al separar los dos primeros dígitos del entero, sin convertirlo a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce un número = ");
        String numero = sc.next(); //Pide el numero y lo almacenas en un String
        int num1 =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numero.charAt(0)) ); //Con esto coges la posicion del primer String con el charAt y la conviertes en String que seguidamente lo conviertes en Entero con Integer.parseInt.
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numero.charAt(1)) );
        int total = num1 + num2; // La suma 
        System.out.println("La suma es " + total);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, existe alguna manera de hacerlo sin almacenar en un String?

Comment: La verdad es que no lo se, yo cuando lo he hecho ha sido de esa forma la que me ha salido pero creo que no hay otra forma. Si encuentras otra forma de hacerlo, comparte si puedes.